# How to refractor this function so it's not necessary to write return true and return false?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
 function isInsideBox(x, y, w, h) {
    if (x > w || x < 0 || y > h || y < 0) {
      return false
    }
    else {
      return true
 }
```

I remember thewere as a way to directly return if conditions are met:

```
 function isInsideBox(x, y, w, h) {
    return (x > w || x < 0 || y > h || y < 0)
 }
```

This doesn't work thought, it returns false all the time.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You used to return `false` when `x > w || x < 0 || y > h || y < 0` was `true`, so you have to invert your test: `return !(x > w || x < 0 || y > h || y < 0)`.

Comment: As @FrédéricHamidi said. But hey, `isInsideBox(-1, -1, -2, -2);` returns `true`.

Comment: one closing curly bracket is missing in your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your short way is working fine in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o56xjfgw/

As @nemoinho mentioned, you must negate the whole expression to get the same result your long version is returning.

So, basically, you must do this:

```
function isInsideBox(x, y, w, h) {
    return !(x > w || x < 0 || y > h || y < 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should negate the result, because you do the same in the first function.

```
function isInsideBox(x, y, w, h) {
    return !(x > w || x < 0 || y > h || y < 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> "**not (A or B)**" is the same as "**(not A) and (not B)**".

```
return  x <= w && x >= 0 && y <= h && y >= 0;
```